# In Swift, how to follow redirection and automatically modify the URL of each redirect request in URLSession to add a reverse proxy?

Tags: swift, redirect, urlsession

The original task is to download something from a remote URL, who might result in multiple redirection. However, for some reason, a reverse proxy is required to be added to each step of the redirection, say, modify the url from `https://xxx` to `https://reverse-proxy/xxx`.

I'm not sure if Swift is able to do it automatically in each step of redirection. So may be we could modify the url string every time after it happens. Hence the question.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using [`URLSession`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsession) to perform the download, provide a [`URLSessionTaskDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsessiontaskdelegate) and implement [`urlSession(_:task:willPerformHTTPRedirection:newRequest:completionHandler:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsessiontaskdelegate/1411626-urlsession).

This allows you to be notified of redirects and lets you supply a new request to a new URL.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, thanks to the answer from @HangarRash, I made it.

First, we need a new `Delegate` class:

```swift
class ReverseProxiedRedirectDelegate: NSObject, URLSessionDelegate, URLSessionTaskDelegate {
    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, willPerformHTTPRedirection response: HTTPURLResponse, newRequest request: URLRequest, completionHandler: @escaping (URLRequest?) -> Void) {
        if let url = request.url {
            let proxyURLString = "REVERSE_PROXY_STRING"
            let newURLString = "\(proxyURLString)\(url.absoluteString)"
            let newURL = URL(string: newURLString)!
            var newRequest = URLRequest(url: newURL)
            newRequest.allHTTPHeaderFields = request.allHTTPHeaderFields
            completionHandler(newRequest)
        } else {
            completionHandler(request)
        }
    }
}
```

Now, we could use it by

```swift
let redirectDelegate = ReverseProxiedRedirectDelegate()
let session = URLSession(configuration: .default, 
                              delegate: redirectDelegate, 
                         delegateQueue: nil)

let targetURL = URL(string: "TARGET_DOWNLOADING_URL")

try await withThrowingTaskGroup(of: Void.self) { group in
    group.addTask {
        let (url, _) = try await session.download(from: targetURL!)
        print(url)
    }
    try await group.waitForAll()
}
```